# How to use DO MAIL action to send email from Control-M File Watcher -input rule file?

Tags: control-m

What is the syntax to be used to to send email from Control-M File Watcher -input rule file when the ON_FILEWATCH condition is met ?

Answer (score 0):

Try in Job's Actions Tab
Add On Do Actions, to be performed according to event such as job completion status and specific output.
On Do Actions
When Job ended Not OK
Send mail notification to email id